# scp get stuck forever after enter password (from Windows to Ubuntu)

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I'm using `ssh` from Windows 10 and connecting to remote Ubuntu server works well.

but when I tried to copy a local file in Windows10 to an Ubuntu server, using `scp`:

`scp -P [port number] [source path] [remoteUsername@remoteIP:/Some/Path]`

after I put the password, it gets stuck forever(pw is correct).

It doesn't show anything.

I tried using `pscp`, but it shows exactly the same problem.

I also tried running command prompt with 'run as an administrator' in Windows 10, but the same result.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you using `scp` from WSL to an external Ubuntu server? Or is this the Windows version of `scp` that you're using?

Comment: @Matigo I think the Ubuntu server somehow blocked incoming `scp`(It's not my own server). I'm not sure if this is a "Windows version", but yeah I used `scp` in Windows10 (`scp` is built-in in Windows 10). After I found that it doesn't work, I installed putty and pscp and tried again, which also failed. I guess a server can block the `scp` connection, right?